# mapping database link(drda) tables to entites in jpa

Tags: java, jpa

I'm using a oracle thin driver to connect to my database.My database links to another db(DB2) with drda specification.My problem is that I can only view the local tables of my database and map them using jpa but I select from drda in sqldeveloper and it works so the problem is definitely with my application development.What do you think is missing?
my application characteristics are as follows:
IDE: MyEclipse 6.5
Struts
Spring 2.5/JPA
Oracle 10g
Tomcat 6.x
Do I need to specify a jta-data-source? Right now I'm not using a data source?
please help me

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure you have followed [these steps](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/gateways.111/b31042/configdrda_gtwy.htm) given by Oracle.